# Given a function $f(x,y)$ find the limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

If it exists, find

$$\lim_{(t,x)\to(0,0)}\frac{t^2\sin^2(x)}{2x^2+t^2}$$

Along the curves $x=mt,t=0,x=at^2,t=ax^2$ the limit approaches 0; the graph also makes $L=0$ seem correct.

So assuming that $L=0$, I start the epsilon delta proof:
$$0<\sqrt{x^2+t^2}<\delta$$
$$\left|\frac{t^2\sin^2(x)}{2x^2+t^2}\right|<\epsilon$$

All attempts I did trying to find a $\delta$ for every $\epsilon$ have just end up circling around and accomplishing nothing.
How am I supposed to complete this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Squeeze Theorem. Notice that $t^{2} < t^{2} + 2x^{2}$, so 
$$ \frac{t^{2}}{t^{2} + 2x^{2}} \leq 1$$ 
Then we have that 
$$
0 \leq \left| \frac{t^{2}\sin^{2}{x}}{2x^{2} + t^{2}} \right| \leq |\sin^{2}{x}|$$
and you can apply the Squeeze Theorem accordingly, noting how $|\sin^{2}{x}|$ behaves as $t,x \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inequality $$|\frac{t^2 \sin^2(x)}{2x^2+t^2}| \le \frac{t^2x^2}{x^2+t^2} \le \frac{t^2x^2}{2|xt|}=\frac{|xt|}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon >0$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{t^2\sin^2 x}{2x^2+t^2}\right|&\le \frac{t^2\,x^2}{x^2+t^2}\\\\
&\le \frac{(x^2+t^2)^2}{x^2+t^2}\\\\
&=x^2+t^2\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $\sqrt{x^2+t^2}<\delta=\sqrt{\epsilon}$.  And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.